# AngularJS - "Controller As" in single page apps

Tags: angularjs

I have a big single page project, that uses $scope.

I read a bit about controller as, and I think I prefer it, mainly because it will give me the flexability to (in the future) move to angular2. But also becasue I can mention to angular on what scope my variable is (like `{{dashboard.thing}}` instead of `{{thing}}`) etc..

But my app does not have a single instance of "ng-controller", because it is a single page app. How can I still use "controller as" in a single page app?
I couldn't find any mention of it on Google.

Comment: Directives and routers allow to use controllerAs too, you don't need ngController directive for this.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks! Didnt even think on this simple solution. http://willi.am/blog/2013/12/03/using-controller-as-syntax-in-angular-routes/